# Do I have to start react-native run-android again after installing new npm packages?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, react-native, npm

I started Mobile App Development recently with react-native.

I want to ask whether `react-native run-android` I should run everytime when I add new npm depenndency?

Comment: Unfortunately, I had to rerun npm every time when using React native. For example, new packages need to be installed on the device.

Comment: Yeah I guessed it so @GökhanGeyik